# since then it is... -- meaning?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses

Usage example with a context:

> Comparing this to the previous result table DISTINCTROW A1 emphasizes the fact that, even though the second and third rows of tblNewA are identical in values, they are different rows, so they both contribute to the final result table. If we were to replace the DISTINCTROW keyword with the word DISTINCT, then the result table would have only one row, **since then** it is the values in each row that form the basis for comparison.

I'm at a loss as to how to understand that phrase. If **then** is removed, the sentence makes perfect sense.

Comment: *then* = *in that case*

Comment: @StoneyB That might be one definition of 'then' but 'since then' means onwards from a period in time or event and not, since in that case.

Comment: @JoeDark But this is not the temporal expression *since then*, for that would make the following clause an independent one, and that would require a semicolon or full stop to close the preceding independent clause. *Since* here has the sense 'for, because'.

Comment: Both StoneyB and JoeDark are correct as "then" can mean either "in that case" meaning the case of using DISTINCT, or "after having replaced DISTINCTROW with DISTINCT", the temporal then.  That the actual explanation of DISTINCT vs DISTINCTROW doesn't seem right is beside the point I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence has the same meaning, with or without the word "then."

Let's look at a simpler sentence to understand:

> If he were six feet tall, I would marry him, since then we would be able to dance comfortably.

"Then" in this sentence--as in your example sentence--is used to emphasize the counterfactual nature of the statement. You're saying that "then"--in the hypothetical case when your tables are set up a certain way, or the hypothetical case where he's six feet tall--only **then** would the thing you're talking about happen.

If you understand these two sentences:

> If he was tall, then we would be able to dance

and

> I married the tallest man, since he was easiest to dance with

then you understand this construction as well--the "then" and "since" are serving the same purposes.